# The "Add Node" button missing

Tags: magento-1.8, cms

I am not able to setup a Node for "Press release" - I cannot see the "Add Node" button in `Admin->CMS->Pages`

Am I missing something?

I went to the `configuration->general->content management` and I still don't see anything that enables me to Manage Hierarchy

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Hierarchy Management is an Enterprise feature, added by the `Enterprise_Cms` module. This functionality is not implemented in CE 1.8.